# Updating current item using jslink

Tags: 2013, list-view, client-object-model, jslink, csom

I am working on a solution where in I have to update current item based on a button click.  I am thinking of using JSLink to generate button with each row,  when this button is clicked i have to refer to the current item and update certain Status.

Do we have any samples for doing something like it?

I know how to transform the list view to include a button in the column,  how do i associate a client side handler that updates the item being clicked.

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript client side object model to update your listitem.

For sample code you can refer following code:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You can attach the listitem update method on "onclick" eventhandler of your custom button.